# Calling convention in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, calling-convention

I've defined a function for a C++/CLI library:

```
extern "C"
{
    INT_PTR __cdecl brl_graphics_Graphics(int Width, int Height, int Depth, int Hertz, int Flags);
}
```

And this is the function that calls it, it's just a wrapper:

```
IntPtr BlitzMax::BlitzMax::Graphics(int Width, int Height, int Depth, int Hertz, int Flags)
{
    return IntPtr(brl_graphics_Graphics(Width, Height, Depth, Hertz, Flags));
}
```

When I call it from a C# application I get a AccessViolationException, for some reason in the disassembly it doesn't use cdecl calling convention:

```
push        dword ptr [ebp+10h] 
push        dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 
push        dword ptr [ebp+8] 
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
call        FFD595B8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully certain what it is that you're trying to do, but this website may help http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2008/12/11/creating-a-managed-wrapper-for-a-lib-file/.

It provides a step-by-step guide for creating a native C++ class (which can just be functions), wrapping them up in a C++/CLI wrapper and then using the wrapper in a C# program.